# Show mysql databases as Linux root user

Tags: mysql, linux, database, command-line-interface, root

I'm logged into a CentOS server and I want to view all mysql databases. So I switched to the Linux root user and I tried logging into mysql. Normally (on other servers) I do this with a simple `mysql` command, but here I get an access denied:

```
[root@our.server.com kramer65]# mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I suppose that if I'm root on Linux I can do anything I want. Is there a way that I can show all Mysql databases as Linux root user?

Answer (score 0):

The system root user is not the same as the root mysql user, and it's possible the system user has no access.

You can give the username to mysql with

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and enter the password for the mysql root user.

---

You can use the same command to connect with *any* mysql user account that is valid within mysql.

Comment: Meaning; if I don't know the mysql root user password I can't access it as Linux root?

Comment: Yes you can like you would to reset the mysql root password. But you could also log as any user that has the right GRANT PRIVILEGES. You will need to restart the services if that is an option. Here the howto i followed https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password. Maria bieng a fork of mysql this apply to both.

Comment: As Louis says, you'd need to grant root@localhost access with a mysql user with the appropriate permissions, but that wasn't what your question was asking. :)

Comment: @kramer65 You won't need to reset the mysql password to access mysql from root. In the command I gave, change 'root' to another user with mysql access and use that password instead when prompted.

Answer (score 0):

From this you can log into your DB as linux root: if restarting servvices is an option:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
mysql -u root
```

Then the usual apply:

```
mysql>SHOW DATABASES;
```